# Query entity by label

Tags: sparql, wikidata-api, wikidata-query-service

From [Wikidata Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org) I want to query the entity [ethanol](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q153) (i.e. Q153).

I can simply do this by querying for the CAS using the following SPARQL:

```sql
SELECT ?cas ?casLabel
WHERE {
  ?cas wdt:P231 "64-17-5". 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

However, I don't find a way, how to query the entity by its name. Is there a property *name*, *compound* or something similar to query the string "ethanol" as below? Or should such a query be constructed differently?

```sql
SELECT ?compound ?compoundLabel
WHERE {
  ?compound wdt:???? "ethanol".
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

---

Another way to search for the string "ethanol" would be to use the wikidata API. However, this is not through the SPARQL endpoint:

https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&format=json&type=item&language=en&limit=50&search=ethanol

Comment: `rdfs:label` is the property to go:`SELECT ?compound ?compoundLabel
WHERE {
  ?compound rdfs:label "ethanol"@en.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}` - please look at the language tag

Comment: and it's also possible to use the entity search via SPARQL: `SELECT ?item WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "EntitySearch" .
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org" .
      bd:serviceParam mwapi:search "ethanol" .
      bd:serviceParam mwapi:language "en" .
      ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item .
      ?num wikibase:apiOrdinal true .
  }
 
} ORDER BY ASC(?num) LIMIT 20`

Comment: Great, works like a charm. I wasn't aware of the `rdfs:label` property. This looks like it has to be an exact match. Can it also match patterns (e.g. `"ethano"@en`)?

Comment: not if you just put the literal as object of a triple pattern. It needs the triple pattern `?compound rdfs:label ?l.` and some filter, e.g. `filter(regex(str(?l), 'ethan'))` or `filter(strstarts(str(?l), 'ethan'))` or `filter(contains(str(?l), 'ethan'))` or just some other regex. Clearly, those filters can be expensive as the whole intermediate resultset has to be processed. And don't forget to restrict the language, i.e. `filter(langmatches(lang(?l), 'en'))`